# Delphi 2010 - MSMQ and event log

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, msmq, event-log

Does anyone have a sample of how to use MSMQ in delphi 2010 to comunicate between 2 delphi applications? I also wanted to log an event on windows event log, but I dont know how to.

Comment: Welcome to StackOferflow.  I suggest you to elaborate on your question before actually posting it.  If you have more than one, it is better to post each one separately.  With simple questions like his one, you're likely to receive answers like [RTFM](http://www.google.com/#q=RTFM) or [STFW](http://www.google.com/#q=STFW), because a [lots of things](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/27363) are there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create the Delphi wrapper code you can use the following command:

```
tlibimp -P c:\windows\system32\mqoa30.tlb
```

This will create a pas and a dcr (component resource) file